Bathroom exhaust fan/exhaust light/vanity lights
My current setup in my bathroom is right inside the door when you walk in, there are 2 switches. Have exhaust fan/light combo. One switch turns on the light of the exhaust fan, other switch turns on exhaust fan itself. On other wall is a switch that turns on vanity lights above sink, but have to walk at least halfway in bathroom to turn this switch on. So what I’m wanting to do is eliminate current vanity lights above sink switch and connect to exhaust light switch, so both exhaust light and vanity lights turn on together at same time. Is it possible to do this and any recommendations on how I would proceed doing so?

What you want can be done, but we need a bit more information to advise you on the how. Can you post pictures of the insides of the boxes with the switches (both the vanity switch and the exhaust switch) and the boxes where the lights and light/fan combo are connected?

It would be helpful to tell us if there is another floor above your bathroom or if it is just attic as well. Some rewiring may need to be done.

Seems something like this would fit your bill—claims "this remote light switch kit can be programmable and expanded at will, enabling 1 switch to control multiple receivers at the same time."  You would install receivers in place of both the fan and vanity switches, and mount the switch wherever you want. https://www.homedepot.com/p/DEWENWILS-Wireless-Remote-Control-Wall-Light-Switch-Kit-Light-Switch-for-Ceiling-Lights-Fans-Lamps-100-ft-RF-Range-HRLS11D1/329997248 (may depend on the current switch configuration, e.g. if you have a duplex switch).

I suggest using a motion detector as the switching agent.
Your choice as to whether you switch all units or just lights.
See Goggle for motion detectors, there are many (instructions too).

Motion detectors are generally a good idea in commercial bathrooms because (a) people don't stick around long and (b) people "forget" to turn off the lights. In a residential bathroom there can be a lot of reasons that it doesn't make sense - e.g., someone wants to soak in a tub for a while with the curtain closed; Sabbath observers who want the light on without any human-controlled switching (including motion detectors), etc.

I use motion detectors for all my bathrooms, but they are attached to a Home Automation system with lots of logic.  The major flaw with this is that the light turns off in the middle of what your ae doing.  But it is still a suggestion.

You can use a variety of Home automation type solutions, depending on your budget.
The first one that hit my search.  Its from Run Less Wire

BASIC KIT: 1 RECEIVER, 1 SWITCH
SKU: RW9-SKWH
The Basic Switch Kit is for controlling 1 light source with 1 single rocker switch. The receiver (controller) is pre-connected to the single rocker switch and is perfect for moving a switch, adding a switch to control a pull-chain light, or adding an additional light fixture to a room without running wires to the switch


